# ValueError: expected sequence of length 4 at dim 2 (got 0)

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am learning Reinforcement learning, i wrote the following code using cross-entropy algorithm to train cartpole game, [official source code from book](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Deep-Reinforcement-Learning-Hands-On/blob/master/Chapter04/01_cartpole.py)

But i am getting the following error :

```
UserWarning: Creating a tensor from a list of numpy.ndarrays is extremely slow. Please consider converting the list to a single numpy.ndarray with numpy.array() before converting to a tensor. (Triggered internally at ..\torch\csrc\utils\tensor_new.cpp:248.)
  obs_t = torch.FloatTensor([obs])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tiklu\OneDrive\Desktop\DRL Resources\codes\basic_rl\cartpole_cross_entropy.py", line 101, in <module>

    for iter_no, batch in enumerate(iterate_batches(env, net, BATCH_SIZE)):
  File "C:\Users\tiklu\OneDrive\Desktop\DRL Resources\codes\basic_rl\cartpole_cross_entropy.py", line 43, in iterate_batches
    obs_t = torch.FloatTensor([obs])
ValueError: expected sequence of length 4 at dim 2 (got 0)
```

Here is the function causing the error :

```
def iterate_batches(env,net,batch_size):
    batch = [] #List of episodes
    episode_reward = 0.0
    episode_steps = []
    obs = env.reset()
    sm = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

    while True:
        #this line 
        obs_t = torch.FloatTensor([obs]) 
        # obs_t = obs_t.view(1, -1)  
        action_props_t = sm(net(obs_t)) #net expects a batch of items
        action_props = action_props_t.data.numpy()[0]

        action = np.random.choice(len(action_props),p = action_props)
        next_obs, reward, is_done, _, _ = env.step(action)

        episode_reward += reward
        episode_steps.append(EpisodeStep(observation=obs,action=action))

        if is_done:
            batch.append(Episode(reward=episode_reward,steps=episode_steps))
            episode_steps = []
            episode_reward = 0.0
            next_obs = env.reset()
            if len(batch)==batch_size:
                yield batch
                batch = []
        obs = next_obs
```

Here is the requirements.txt, if you want to try

```
gym==0.26.2
numpy==1.24.3
tensorboardX==2.6
torch==2.0.0
```

since the code from book is giving the error, and i don't have much experience with numpy and tensor library. I would really appreciate if you could help.

Answer (score 0):

In the recent versions of OpenAI gym, `env.reset()` returns a tuple of `(observation, info)` and not just `observation` like in the previous versions. So, replace `obs = env.reset()` with `obs, _ = env.reset()` and your code should start working.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the env.reset(), in recent version of OpenAI gym, `env.step(action)` returns 5 elements instead of 4. replace:
`next_obs, reward, is_done, _= env.step(action)` with `next_obs, reward, is_done, _, _= env.step(action)`